# mongodb exception connection failed

Tags: mongodb, windows-7, nosql

when I'm trying to open mongodb with command prompt I'm getting a error message like

> D:\mongo-bd\bin>mongo.exe
>   MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
>   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   2018-04-27T18:50:28.340+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1
>   :27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
>   2018-04-27T18:50:28.340+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ser
>   ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

I have tried by running mongo --repair command but still I'm facing this problem.

Comment: Check if there's mongod running (cmd>tasklist). Then if the tcp/27017 port is listening (cmd>netstat)

Comment: yes i have seen in the tasklist there is mongod in the list

Comment: And how about port? call cmd> netstat -a

Answer (score 0):

> ## 1 First set up the data directory - google it
>
> ## 2 then run the
>
> {installationDirectory}/MongoDB/Server/{serverVersion}/bin/mongod.exe 
>   to start the service
>
> ## 3 Get into the shell
>
> {installationDirectory}/MongoDB/Server/{serverVersion}/bin/mongo.exe